Custom User Controls Disappear from Windows Forms Designer in VB.NET
I'm encountering an issue where occasionally custom user controls disappear from the Windows Forms Designer in VB.NET. The only thing that remains of these controls is the Friend WithEvents declaration, but all other references (e.g., inside containers, layouts, etc.) are completely gone.
 Friend WithEvents lblWidth As C_TextBoxUnits
 Friend WithEvents lblLength As C_TextBoxUnits
 Friend WithEvents lblSRHeight As C_TextBoxUnits

Ill attached the code for the control below.
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Windows.Forms
<DefaultEvent("TextChanged")>
Public Class C_TextBoxUnits
    Inherits TextBox

    ' Private variables to hold the unit
    Private _unit As String = ""  ' Default unit
    Private _suppressTextChanged As Boolean = False

    ' Constructor
    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
        ' Optionally, set default properties here
    End Sub

    ' Public property to get/set the unit
    <Browsable(True)>
    <Category("Appearance")>
    <Description("Gets or sets the unit to append to the text.")>
    Public Property Unit As String
        Get
            Return _unit
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            ' Trim the unit to remove any whitespace
            _unit = value.Trim()
            UpdateTextDisplay()
        End Set
    End Property

    ' Override the Text property
    Public Overrides Property Text As String
        Get
            ' Return the text without the unit
            Return GetTextWithoutUnit()
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            ' Set the text without the unit
            MyBase.Text = value
            ' Update the display to include the unit if appropriate
            UpdateTextDisplay()
        End Set
    End Property

    ' Get the text without the unit
    Private Function GetTextWithoutUnit() As String
        Dim textWithUnit As String = MyBase.Text

        Dim unitToCheck As String = GetUnitToCheck()

        If textWithUnit.EndsWith(unitToCheck, StringComparison.Ordinal) Then
            textWithUnit = textWithUnit.Substring(0, textWithUnit.Length - unitToCheck.Length)
        End If

        Return textWithUnit
    End Function

    ' Update the TextBox display to include the unit if text is numeric
    Private Sub UpdateTextDisplay()
        If _suppressTextChanged Then Return

        _suppressTextChanged = True

        Dim cursorPosition As Integer = Me.SelectionStart

        Dim textWithoutUnit As String = GetTextWithoutUnit()
        Dim unitToAppend As String = GetUnitToCheck()

        ' Remove all spaces from the text
        Dim textWithoutSpaces As String = textWithoutUnit.Replace(" ", "")

        ' Check if the text without spaces is numeric
        If IsNumericText(textWithoutSpaces) Then
            ' Use the text without spaces
            textWithoutUnit = textWithoutSpaces

            ' Update the text with the unit
            MyBase.Text = textWithoutUnit & unitToAppend
        Else
            ' If not numeric, use the original text without unit
            MyBase.Text = textWithoutUnit  ' Do not append unit
        End If

        ' Set the cursor position appropriately
        If cursorPosition > textWithoutUnit.Length Then
            Me.SelectionStart = textWithoutUnit.Length
        Else
            Me.SelectionStart = cursorPosition
        End If

        _suppressTextChanged = False
    End Sub

    ' Determine whether to include a space before the unit and get the unit string
    Private Function GetUnitToCheck() As String
        Dim trimmedUnit As String = _unit.Trim()

        ' Units that should not have a space before them
        Dim unitsWithoutSpace As String() = {"""", "'"}
        If unitsWithoutSpace.Contains(trimmedUnit) Then
            Return trimmedUnit
        Else
            Return " " & trimmedUnit
        End If
    End Function

    ' Check if the text is numeric
    Private Function IsNumericText(text As String) As Boolean
        ' Use Double.TryParse to check if it's a valid number
        Dim dummy As Double
        Return Double.TryParse(text, dummy)
    End Function

    ' Override OnTextChanged event
    Protected Overrides Sub OnTextChanged(e As EventArgs)
        If Not _suppressTextChanged Then
            UpdateTextDisplay()
        End If
        MyBase.OnTextChanged(e)
    End Sub

    ' Optional: Override Paste to prevent pasting unit
    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
        Const WM_PASTE As Integer = &H302
        If m.Msg = WM_PASTE Then
            ' Handle paste operation
            Dim clipboardText As String = Clipboard.GetText()
            ' Remove unit if present
            Dim unitToCheck As String = GetUnitToCheck()
            If clipboardText.EndsWith(unitToCheck, StringComparison.Ordinal) Then
                clipboardText = clipboardText.Substring(0, clipboardText.Length - unitToCheck.Length)
            End If
            Me.SelectedText = clipboardText
            Return
        End If
        MyBase.WndProc(m)
    End Sub


End Class

I want to make them stop vanishing if at all possible.
